# How can I solve the 'ValueError: pic should be 2/3 dimensional. Got 4 dimensions' when using PyTorch for image processing?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, torchvision

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
from capsnet import CapsNet
from data_loader import Dataset
from tqdm import tqdm


USE_CUDA = True if torch.cuda.is_available() else False
BATCH_SIZE = 100
N_EPOCHS = 30
LEARNING_RATE = 0.01
MOMENTUM = 0.9

'''
Config class to determine the parameters for capsule net
'''


class Config:
    def __init__(self, dataset='mnist'):
        if dataset == 'mnist':
            # CNN (cnn)
            self.cnn_in_channels = 1
            self.cnn_out_channels = 256
            self.cnn_kernel_size = 9

            # Primary Capsule (pc)
            self.pc_num_capsules = 8
            self.pc_in_channels = 256
            self.pc_out_channels = 32
            self.pc_kernel_size = 9
            self.pc_num_routes = 32 * 6 * 6

            # Digit Capsule (dc)
            self.dc_num_capsules = 10
            self.dc_num_routes = 32 * 6 * 6
            self.dc_in_channels = 8
            self.dc_out_channels = 16

            # Decoder
            self.input_width = 28
            self.input_height = 28

        elif dataset == 'cifar10':
            # CNN (cnn)
            self.cnn_in_channels = 3
            self.cnn_out_channels = 256
            self.cnn_kernel_size = 9

            # Primary Capsule (pc)
            self.pc_num_capsules = 8
            self.pc_in_channels = 256
            self.pc_out_channels = 32
            self.pc_kernel_size = 9
            self.pc_num_routes = 32 * 8 * 8

            # Digit Capsule (dc)
            self.dc_num_capsules = 10
            self.dc_num_routes = 32 * 8 * 8
            self.dc_in_channels = 8
            self.dc_out_channels = 16

            # Decoder
            self.input_width = 32
            self.input_height = 32
        elif dataset == 'custom':
            # CNN (cnn)
            self.cnn_in_channels = 3
            self.cnn_out_channels = 256
            self.cnn_kernel_size = 9

            # Primary Capsule (pc)
            self.pc_num_capsules = 8
            self.pc_in_channels = 256
            self.pc_out_channels = 32
            self.pc_kernel_size = 9
            self.pc_num_routes = 32 * 8 * 8

            # Digit Capsule (dc)
            self.dc_num_capsules = 10
            self.dc_num_routes = 32 * 8 * 8
            self.dc_in_channels = 4
            self.dc_out_channels = 16

            # Decoder
            self.input_width = 32
            self.input_height = 24
        elif dataset == 'your own dataset':
            pass


def train(model, optimizer, train_loader, epoch):
    capsule_net = model
    capsule_net.train()
    n_batch = len(list(enumerate(train_loader)))
    total_loss = 0
    for batch_id, (data, target) in enumerate(tqdm(train_loader)):

        target = torch.sparse.torch.eye(10).index_select(dim=0, index=target)
        data, target = Variable(data), Variable(target)

        if USE_CUDA:
            data, target = data.cuda(), target.cuda()

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output, reconstructions, masked = capsule_net(data)
        loss = capsule_net.loss(data, output, target, reconstructions)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        correct = sum(np.argmax(masked.data.cpu().numpy(), 1) == np.argmax(target.data.cpu().numpy(), 1))
        train_loss = loss.item()
        total_loss += train_loss
        if batch_id % 100 == 0:
            tqdm.write("Epoch: [{}/{}], Batch: [{}/{}], train accuracy: {:.6f}, loss: {:.6f}".format(
                epoch,
                N_EPOCHS,
                batch_id + 1,
                n_batch,
                correct / float(BATCH_SIZE),
                train_loss / float(BATCH_SIZE)
                ))
    tqdm.write('Epoch: [{}/{}], train loss: {:.6f}'.format(epoch,N_EPOCHS,total_loss / len(train_loader.dataset)))


def test(capsule_net, test_loader, epoch):
    capsule_net.eval()
    test_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    for batch_id, (data, target) in enumerate(test_loader):

        target = torch.sparse.torch.eye(10).index_select(dim=0, index=target)
        data, target = Variable(data), Variable(target)

        if USE_CUDA:
            data, target = data.cuda(), target.cuda()

        output, reconstructions, masked = capsule_net(data)
        loss = capsule_net.loss(data, output, target, reconstructions)

        test_loss += loss.item()
        correct += sum(np.argmax(masked.data.cpu().numpy(), 1) ==
                       np.argmax(target.data.cpu().numpy(), 1))

        # Burada diğer işlemleri gerçekleştir (örneğin, metrik hesaplamaları)

    tqdm.write(
        "Epoch: [{}/{}], test accuracy: {:.6f}, loss: {:.6f}".format(epoch, N_EPOCHS, correct / len(test_loader.dataset),
                                                                  test_loss / len(test_loader)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    torch.manual_seed(1)
    dataset = 'custom'
    # dataset = 'mnist'
    config = Config(dataset)
    mnist = Dataset(dataset, BATCH_SIZE)

    capsule_net = CapsNet(config)
    capsule_net = torch.nn.DataParallel(capsule_net)
    if USE_CUDA:
        capsule_net = capsule_net.cuda()
    capsule_net = capsule_net.module

    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(capsule_net.parameters())

    for e in range(1, N_EPOCHS + 1):
        train(capsule_net, optimizer, mnist.train_loader, e)
        test(capsule_net, mnist.test_loader, e)
```

I added multiple (19) train data for one original image and it's size on disk is 72.0 KB. I am using the "custom" dataset for the data to be trained.

But I got this error: **raise ValueError(f"pic should be 2/3 dimensional. Got {pic.ndimension()} dimensions.")
ValueError: pic should be 2/3 dimensional. Got 4 dimensions.** How to solve this problem?